# Correct definition for a limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am trying to figure out if this is a correct definition of limit:

> If for every $a>0$ there exists $b>0$ such that for every $x \in (x_{0}-a,x_{0}+a)$ we have that $|f(x) - l| < b$, then we say that the limit of $f$ as $x$ goes to $x_{0}$ is $l$.

Is this definition correct?

Comment: This is at least not a great definition. If $a = 0$, then $(x_0 - a, x_0 + a) = \emptyset$, hence the definition stops really  making sense, although, logically, you could say it is correct. Just google "epsilon delta definition limit" and I'm sure you can find a more workable version.

Answer (score 0):

No, you have your quantifiers in the wrong order.  Consider the function
$$
    f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x > 0; \\ 0 & x= 0 \\ -1 & x < 0 \end{cases}
$$
I claim that (**according to your definition**) $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0$.

*Proof*.  Given $a > 0$, let $b=2$.  Choose a point $x$ in the interval $(-a,a)$.  Then $f(x)$ is at least $-1$ and at most $1$.  In particular $|f(x)|<2$.  Since this can be done for all $a>0$, the definition is satisfied. $\Box$

But that doesn't square with anyone else's idea of limit.

If you swap the order of the quantifiers, and also rule out the condition at the point $x=x_0$, then you get the ordinary $\epsilon$,$\delta$ definition with the names of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ changed to $b$ and $a$.